# Developing an winform to users on a Terminal Server?

Tags: .net, winforms, remote-desktop

I'm going to have an winform app running on a Windows Server 2012 with several users over Remote Desktop.

If I place my app in a folder, how will I update it? I guess lots of files are in use and cannot be updated.

What would you do?

Thanks
Mojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run in to this exact issue and discovered a interesting work around. Windows will let you **move** a file that is in use.

What I do is I make a folder called `Old` in the install directory of the program, I then move the exe in to that folder and copy over my new exe.

Any new people who log on use the new exe and I give it a day to let all the old users log off (the timeout period on our RDP server kicks inactive people after 4 hours so everyone usually gets logged off overnight) and then I delete the `Old` folder I made at the start.

Comment: Yes, this approach works. Windows Installer actually does this under the covers, so if you package your app as an MSI (using e.g. WiX), everything Just Works (Windows Installer takes care of deleting the temporarily moved files as well).

Comment: Emmm what if I need to move replace an entire directory? I get an access denied when trying to "move" a directory with files in use?

Comment: That, I do not know how to solve. You can only move files, not folders. Sorry :(